# Evaluate the Integral: $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+6x-8}}dx$ by First Completing the Square and Using the Substitution: u=3x+1

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Evaluate the Integral: $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+6x-8}}dx$ by First Completing the Square and Using the Substitution: u=3x+1

I first divided the entire polynomial by 9 so as to have a leading coefficient of 1

$\frac{9x^2}{9}+\frac{6x}{9}-\frac{8}{9}$

My result was $x^2+\frac{6x}{9}-\frac{8}{9}$

I took the coefficient of the second term and divided it by 2 which gave me $\frac{6}{18}$

I then split the constant away from the polynomial:

$x^2+\frac{6x}{9}\rightarrow -\frac{8}{9}$

and added and subtracted $\frac{6}{18}$

$x^2+\frac{6x}{9}+\frac{6}{18}\rightarrow-\frac{6}{18} -\frac{8}{9}$

that gave me $(x+\frac{6}{18})^2-\frac{10}{18}$

Obviously this is not a legitimate square. What have I done wrong?
How can I use the u=3x+1 with this value?

Comment: the error was that you took half of the coefficient on the $x$ term, but forgot to square it. You should be adding $(\frac{3}{9})^2$. One  could also ensure that the fractions are reduced as much as possible, but I digress.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+6x-8}}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+6x+1-9}}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(3x+1)^2-3^2}}$$
Using $u=3x+1$ we have $du=3dx$. So
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(3x+1)^2-3^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{(u)^2-3^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3} \log(u+\sqrt{(u)^2-3^2})+c$$
$$=\frac{1}{3} \log(3x+1+\sqrt{(3x+1)^2-3^2})+c$$

Comment: So, I don't divide out the leading coefficient?

Comment: Not needed. As you can see.

Comment: My teacher stressed the need to have a leading coefficient of 1? I find it odd she would assign a problem like this? Nonetheless, what is your method called? Is their a tutorial I can view?

Comment: According to the book your answer is incorrect.

Comment: One integration can be done in many ways. So the book answer might not match mine. Anyway, if you differentiate my answer, you will get the integrand back. Check that and if my working procedure is logical or not. The answer might not match, that's not a worry at all. Your maths must be logical...that's it.

Comment: Calling math logical is a slippery slope. Way to many variables and "tricks"to actually call it logical. Nonetheless, how did you complete the square? Can you recommend a tutorial.

Comment: Completing the square is as you can see...you just need to observe...I cant recommend you any tutorial as I myself studied these things by practising problems again and again.BTW......Why the downvote??

Comment: I have up voted after you edited.

Comment: @Aniket. If it was a^2 - x^2, then sine inverse is OK. In this case it is log.

Comment: @Shailesh Missed it somehow. Finally noticed it.

Comment: NP. Answers can differ, but only by a constant. A trig will not be easily equivalent to a log